# facebook login with jquery and send data to php page

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

I am trying to login my users via facebook.I am not quite sure what  have not done,in this code.Nothing is being entered in the database.From the page fb_action.php

When  login using the facebook button its all successful apart from the data being send to the fb_action.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
        appId      : 'APP_ID', // replace your app id here
        channelUrl : 'channel.html',
        status     : true,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true 
        });
    };
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

                /*** USER TRIGGERED JS ***/
                var username = '';
                var userid = '';
                var userEmail = ''; 
                var userMac = '$(mac)';

    function FBLogin(){
        FB.login(function(response){

            if(response.authResponse){
                //console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + ', ' + response.email + '.');

                                username = response.name;
                                userid = response.id;
                                userEmail = response.email;

                                var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState === 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
            alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);
        }
    };
    //send with POST fb_username=username&fb_userid=userid&fb_email=userEmail
    ajaxRequest.open('GET','http://127.0.0.1/signup-portal/27340571/fb_action.php?fb_username='+username+'&fb_userid='+userid+'&fb_email='+userEmail+'&fb_mac='+userMac,true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);


                                 window.location.href = "$(link-login-only)?dst=$(link-orig-esc)&username=T-$(mac-esc)";
                            });

                        } else {
                             alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                            showErrorScreen();
                        }

        }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});

                //window.location.href = "//google.com";
    }
    function showErrorScreen() {
                     alert('showErrorScreen');
                }


    </script>
```

My php page has this code to be able to post data in the database

```
define('ZIL_ROOT', './');
// define this to stop other files being included when they shouldnt
define('scr_ind', true);

require_once 'include/db/connect.php';

$userPIN = $_GET['fb_userid'];
$password = 'tabanax';
$subscriber_email = $_GET['fb_email'];
$firstName = $_GET['fb_username'];
$subscriber_phone = $_GET['fb_mac'];

$sql3 = "INSERT INTO ".$configValues['CONFIG_DB_TBL_DALOUSERINFO'].
                    " (id, username,portalloginpassword, firstname, lastname, mobilephone, email, creationdate, creationby, enableportallogin, mng_hs_usr)".
                    " VALUES (0,'$userPIN','$password','".$firstName."','".$lastName."', '".$subscriber_phone."','".$subscriber_email."', ".
                    "'".NOW."','fb','1','".$configValues['CONFIG_HOTSPOT_BUSINESS_ID']."'".
                    ")";
            $res3 = mysql_query($sql3);
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: `.NOW.` that's treated as a constant, btw. `$configValues` don't know how that's being populated from.

Comment: with jquery? where are you using jquery?

Comment: btw, you REALLY need to read about security, especially SQL injections and stuff. this is really bad code. and use PDO.

Comment: @Fred-ii- $configValues is provided for in config file - same as .NOW. i am concerned about the facebook login script.... provided the second code to show how i collect data as simple as i possible.

Comment: @luschn i am aware but this application is still in development interface

Comment: that's a very bad excuse for using very old and very bad code...